# = and == difference in If statement Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I am facing something strange here. Please help me understand if I am missing something. My if condition was supposed to be:

```
if(configuredPdf == true)
```

But by mistake I had written:

```
if(configuredPdf = true)
```

And my Eclipse compiler does not ask me to correct it. Then I assume there is no compile time or checked exception. So:

```
(configuredPdf = true)
```

Returns a boolean?

Comment: what is the type of `configuredPdf`, boolean i guess?

Comment: that is right if configuredPdf is of compatible type

Comment: `== true` seems a bit redundant.

Comment: @Biffen It IS redundant

Comment: You are correct. it is redundent.Corrected it.
Thank you for the Answers Here is an another Interesting Addon to the Question ..can we actually edit the Return Type other than the object reference itself after the assignment. Like a .toString() method of the object. Person p; Signature objectSignature = (p = new Person())

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, `configuredPdf = true` assigns `true` to your variable and returns `true`. Therefore `if (configuredPdf = true)` is a valid syntax even though it's usually a bug.

It's safer to use `if (configuredPdf)` to avoid this kind of typo.

Comment: here's what I use: i write constant on the left side. `if (true == configuredPdf)` when mistyped to contain `=` in `if (true = configuredPdf)` gives compilation error.

Comment: @Willmore: Better yet: `if (configuredPdf)` There's no need for Yoda comparisons in Java.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes for booleans works this `if (configuredPdf)`

Comment: @Willmore See I what you did there :)

Comment: @Willmore: Right, and booleans are the only case where Java will allow you to do `if (x = y)`. It won't with any other data type.

Comment: @Willmore though for other types, expressions of the form `if (num = 4)` will simply fail to pass compilation.

Comment: seems there is no gain using yoda conditions

Comment: Yes..Going by above logic :
String x ; 
String y;
x =  y= "Test"; //holds good.
but if(x=y) does not as it doesn return boolean..makes sense

Comment: Thank you for the Answers 
Here is an another Interesting Addon to the Question ..can we actually edit the Return Type other than the object reference itself after the assignment. Like a .toString() method of the object. 
    Person p;     Signature objectSignature = (p = new Person());

Comment: @Kumar I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you mean something like - ` Person p; Signature objectSignature = (p = new Person()).getSignature();`? (assuming the Person class has a getSignature method that returns a Signature reference). That should work.

Comment: Object a = new object() The returns the reference of the object just created as in 
Object b = a = new new object();
Can we change the ReturnType to what we need.Like 
Signature objectSignature = (p = new Person()); Where decide in the class what needs to be returned on object creation.
Anyways its a stupid question..not so important..just ignore it if its clumsy

Comment: @Kumar Well, if `Person` is a sub-class of (or implements) `Signature`, your assignment would be valid. Otherwise it won't.

Answer (score 8):

An assignment is an expression which returns the value you assigned. e.g. `a = b = true` will assign `true` to `a` and `b`.

The reason `boolean` type was added was to avoid this sort of bug.  In C for example you can write

```
if (a = 1)
```

and anything non-negative is true.

While you can still make a mistake with boolean types, instead of writing

```
if (a == true)
if (b == false)
```

you can write

```
if (a)
if (!b)
```

A more common example is

```
for(String line; ((line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
    // process the line.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

An *assignment expression*'s result is always the value that was assigned, including when assigning to a boolean. This is covered by [JLS§15.26](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26):

> At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable after the assignment has occurred.

So yes, `configuredPdf = true` assigns `true` to `configuredPdf`, and the result of that expression is `true`.

Similarly, `x = y = 5;` assigns `5` to `y`, and the result of `y = 5` is `5`, which is then assigned to `x`.

Fundamentally, what you wanted was:

```
if (configuredPdf)
```

There's never any need to compare a boolean variable with `true` or `false`, just use the `if (theVariable)` (for comparing with `true`) or `if (!theVariable)` (for comparing with `false`). Getting in that habit will protect you from inadvertent assignment.

The only time actually comparing boolean values is useful is when they're *both* variables, e.g. `if (thisFlag == thatFlag)` or `if (thisFlag != thatFlag`).

To avoid accidental assignment in that situation, either:

1. Use a linter that checks for this
2. "double bang" the first flag:

   ```
   if (!!thisFlag == thatFlag)
   ```

   ...although as you pointed out if you can accidentally type `=` instead of `==`, presumably you can accidentally type `!` instead of `!!` :-)
3. Use an old C idiom (this is what I use):

   ```
   if (!thisFlag == !thatFlag)
   ```

Comment: plus 1 for mentioning the motivation for such seemingly peculiar behavior. Other answers miss that.

Comment: The double bang is nice and funny, if were that careful to add a double bang, i would have definitely not missed == :) .

THANK YOU very much for the Answers.

Comment: @user3729911: LOL! Good point, if we can accidentally type `=` instead of `==`, presumably we can accidentally type `!` instead of `!!`! :-) I actually usually use an old C idiom: `if (!thisFlag == !thatFlag)`.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is when the compiler comes to the if condition in your code, it assigns 'configuredpdf' to be true. Thus the condition

```
    if(configuredpdf = true)
```

Becomes true and the loop executes successfully. However, the problem arises when we DON'T want this loop to be true. At that time when, for a given input, the compiler parses the if condition, it forcibly becomes true and executes the code written in if condition executes even if the data entered does not agreeing. That is why you will find that your code has a bug at the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

`configuredPdf` must be  a boolean for `if(configuredPdf = true)` to compile.

`configuredPdf = true` will assign  `true` to `configuredPdf` and thus `if` will succeed.

Comment: Here is an another Interesting Addon to the Question ..can we actually edit the Return Type other than the object reference itself after the assignment. Like a .toString() method of the object.
    Person p;
    Signature objectSignature = (p = new Person());